# null cannot be cast to non-null type java.lang.String

Tags: android, kotlin

Getting the error:

> 2022-01-03 21:48:22.093 8414-8414/com.example.newsorgapi
> E/InputEventSender: Exception dispatching finished signal.
> 2022-01-03 21:48:22.093 8414-8414/com.example.newsorgapi E/MessageQueue-JNI:
> Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback
> 2022-01-03 21:48:22.104 8414-8414/com.example.newsorgapi E/MessageQueue-JNI:
> java.lang.NullPointerException: null cannot be cast to non-null type
> java.lang.String
> at com.example.newsorgapi.MainActivity$onCreateOptionsMenu$1.onQueryTextChange(MainActivity.kt:77)

```
override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {

        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menuitems, menu)

        val item = menu.findItem(R.id.search)
        val searchView = item?.actionView as SearchView
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(object: SearchView.OnQueryTextListener{
            override fun onQueryTextSubmit(query: String?): Boolean {
                return true
            }

            @SuppressLint("NotifyDataSetChanged")
            override fun onQueryTextChange(newText: String?): Boolean {

                tempnene.clear()
                val searchtext = newText!!.lowercase(Locale.getDefault())
                if(searchtext.isNotEmpty()){

                    tempne.forEach {

                        if(it.description.lowercase(Locale.getDefault()).contains(searchtext)){

                            tempnene.add(it)
                        }
                    }
                    binding.recycler.adapter!!.notifyDataSetChanged()
                }
                else{

                    tempnene.clear()
                    tempnene.addAll(tempne)
                    binding.recycler.adapter!!.notifyDataSetChanged()
                }


                return true
            }


        })

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu)
    }
```

Comment: It's seems that `searchView` can be null. Check your XML Layout and/or add a null-check in your code to fix this NPE

Comment: When you call `newText!!.lowercase` you're asserting that `newText` is not `null`, even though you haven't checked if that's actually the case.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a null-safe operator to avoid such issues. Your search view can be a null object as your item is nullable. So it is better to type check cast it and make the type SearchView nullable.

But, your problem is in `onQueryTextChange`, newText is nullable, but you are using a non-null assertation operator on it. When the newText is not null, there is no problem. But once it gets a null value, it will throw a null pointer exception as you are forcing it to be a non-null value. So, we need to use null-safe operator there as well.

Change your code to be like this, and your issue will be resolved.

```
override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {

        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menuitems, menu)

        val item = menu.findItem(R.id.search)
        val searchView: SearchView? = item?.actionView as? SearchView
        searchView?.setOnQueryTextListener(object: SearchView.OnQueryTextListener{
            override fun onQueryTextSubmit(query: String?): Boolean {
                return true
            }

            @SuppressLint("NotifyDataSetChanged")
            override fun onQueryTextChange(newText: String?): Boolean {

                tempnene.clear()

                val searchtext = newText?.lowercase(Locale.getDefault())
                if(searchtext.isNotNullOrEmpty()){

                    tempne.forEach {

                        if(it.description.lowercase(Locale.getDefault()).contains(searchtext)){

                            tempnene.add(it)
                        }
                    }
                    binding.recycler.adapter!!.notifyDataSetChanged()
                }
                else{

                    tempnene.clear()
                    tempnene.addAll(tempne)
                    binding.recycler.adapter!!.notifyDataSetChanged()
                }


                return true
            }


        })

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu)
    }
```